# Question from bit twiddling site

Tags: bit-manipulation, code-analysis

Here is the code:

```
unsigned int v;  // word value to compute the parity of
v ^= v >> 16;
v ^= v >> 8;
v ^= v >> 4;
v &= 0xf;
return (0x6996 >> v) & 1;
```

It computes the parity of given word, `v`. What is the meaning of 0x6996?

The number 0x6996 in binary is `110100110010110`.

Comment: what is your question? how does this code works? or how to calculate something? you are asking questions over and over in same unclear manner, please try to be **specific**

Comment: @Andrey: This time he clearly asks what the meaning of value `0x6996` is in this code. IMO it's a specific enough question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the algorithm is compressing the 32-bit int into a 4-bit value of the same parity by successive bitwise ORs and then ANDing with `0xf` so that there are only positive bits in the least-significant 4-bits. In other words after line 5, `v` will be an int between 0 and 15 inclusive.

It then shifts that magic number (`0x6996`) to the right by this 0-16 value and returns only the least significant bit (`& 1`).

That means that if there is a `1` in the `v` bit position of `0x6996` then the computed parity bit is 1, otherwise it's 0 - for example if in line 5 `v` is calculated as 2 then ` is returned, if it was 3 then 0 would be returned.

Answer (score 8):

The first four lines convert `v` to a 4-bit number (0 to 15) that has the same parity as the original. The 16-bit number `0x6996` contains the parity of all the numbers from 0 to 15, and the right-shift is used to select the correct bit. It is similar to using a lookup table:

```
//This array contains the parity of the numbers 0 to 15
char parities[16] = {0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0};
return parities[v];
```

Note that the array entries are the same as the bits of 0x6996. Using `(0x6996 >> v) & 1` gives the same result, but doesn't require the memory access.